# Import data from Excel and plot in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, import, data, excel

I'm trying to `Plot` data in *Mathematica* that I upload from *Excel*.

The *Excel* file has 5 columns. The first column I would like to be the x-values, and the remaining 4 columns are y-values.

**How to plot each of the curves on the same axes?**

I tried the following:

```
data = Import["cyclic-nc-100-t2-t1 formatted.xlsx"];
ListPlot[data]
```

and it won't work...

While it does work for an Excel spreadsheet with just two columns (first column being $x$, second column being $y$).

The following link lets you download the spreadsheet
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZoiwC_F9o3tQOPvQWPQVP1jR05VZ9AXz/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3):

This is very similar to the answer by @DavidG.Stork, but I would encourage to always limit the scope of the definitions, in this case using [`With`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html), but also [`Module`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html) and [`Block`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html). Also, indenting code makes it more readable.

```
With[
 {
  data = Import["cyclic-nc-100-t2-t1 formatted.xlsx"]
  },
 ListPlot[
  {
   data[[1, All, {1, 2}]],
   data[[1, All, {1, 3}]],
   data[[1, All, {1, 4}]],
   data[[1, All, {1, 5}]]
   }
  , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

```
ListPlot[{{xdata=data[[All,1]],data[[All,2]]},
                            {xdata,data[[All,3]]},
                            {xdata,data[[All,4]]}}]
```